# How to get Process executable path using ManagementEventWatcher

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, wmi, managementeventwatcher

I know how to get ProcessID and ProcessName using ManagementEventWatcher. My code is working good.

**What i need?**
I want to get a Path of Process.
I want to Print ProcessID, ProcessName and ProcessPath.

**MY CODE :**

```
Dim processStartEvent As ManagementEventWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace")
Dim processStopEvent As ManagementEventWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler processStartEvent.EventArrived, AddressOf Me.processStartEvent_EventArrived
    processStartEvent.Start()
    AddHandler processStopEvent.EventArrived, AddressOf Me.processStopEvent_EventArrived
    processStopEvent.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub processStartEvent_EventArrived(EventArrivedEventArgs, e)
    Dim processName As String = e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString
    Dim processID As String = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessID").Value).ToString
    FileIO.WriteToFile("Process ID: " & processID & vbNewLine)
    FileIO.WriteToFile("Process Name: " & processName & vbNewLine)
End Sub

Private Sub processStopEvent_EventArrived(EventArrivedEventArgs, e)
    Dim processName As String = e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString
    Dim processID As String = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessID").Value).ToString
    FileIO.WriteToFile("Process ID: " & processID & vbNewLine)
    FileIO.WriteToFile("Process Name: " & processName & vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

> *if you are not familiar with VB.net you can answer in C# as well.*

Answer (score 0):

What about get process path from `processID` .?
like that

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(processID).MainModule.FileName;
```

Here some infromation about `MainModule` [Process.MainModule Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=netframework-4.8)

And i don't know why here you convert from `string` to `int` then from `int` to `string`

```
Dim processID As String = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessID").Value).ToString()
```